# SQL Server - Bulk data Insert (talking data from a flat file tab delimited source) and creating temp tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, bulkinsert

My goal is to take raw data I'm receiving from a file path and insert that into a new table or temporary table. The problem is there are no headers for the data I am getting. The file is a flat file with tab delimiters.

Information:
The file names all start with the same substring: DBA_NG_INBOUND_ELIG_
And the file path is the same for all files: \DBAediarchive\shared\edi\ediarchive\Inbound\TPV\Eligibility

Ideally I'd like to just store the last 7 days worth of files in a temporary table and delete that data and replace it every 7 days. But maybe I make a stored procedure to accomplish that (or all of this)

My solution would be something like this (there will be more than 1 column and I can refine the data types for the columns as well:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (
    Column1 VARCHAR(50),
    Column2 VARCHAR(50),
    Column3 VARCHAR(50),
    Column4 VARCHAR(50),
    Column5 VARCHAR(50),
    Column6 VARCHAR(50),
    Column7 VARCHAR(50),
    Column8 VARCHAR(50),
    Column9 VARCHAR(50),
    Column10 VARCHAR(50)
)

BULK INSERT #TempTable
FROM '\\DBAediarchive\shared\edi\ediarchive\Inbound\TPV\Eligibility\DBA_NG_INBOUND_ELIG_*.txt'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 1
);

Is this an efficient solution? Additionally if someone has a stored procedure method that would pick up only 7 days worth of files from that path that would be an ideal solution.
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server) to define better names and correct data types of the columns whilst reading in the data?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Im not sure I understand - can you show in generic code how youd define your flat file format?

Comment: The linked article shows you how to create legacy format files and the newer XML format files. Only you know the specifics of the column names and the required data types because we don't know what data is in your delimited files.